# Callback to update GUI after asynchronous ServiceStack web service call

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, callback, servicestack

I need to refresh a `ListBox` in my GUI once the asynchronous call to a web service has successfully returned.  It is not so simple as dumping the results of the web service call in to an `ObservableCollection` since the results are actually put in to an indexed `Dictionary` and only the top 1000 results are displayed in the `ListBox` at any given time.

I have code to pick out the top 1000 results, and to refresh the `ListBox` display, I just need to figure out some way to call it once the result has returned succesfully.

```
this.client.GetAsync<RepositoryResponse>(string.Format
    ("/repository?Dto={0}", reader.Dto.ToJson()),
    r => ReadSuccessCallback(r),
    (r, x) => ReadErrorCallback(r, x));
```

This code is executed in a different dialog box than the window where the GUI update is made.  I call this asynchronous get as I am closing the one dialog box, and hope to refresh the `ListBox` in the original window.  I tried passing an `Action` object to be executed in the `ReadSuccessCallback` method, and it executes correctly, but gives me an error saying that the `Items` collection behind the `ListBox` belongs to a different thread, and can not be changed.

How can I get a new chunk of 1000 items (and refresh the display of the `ListBox`) only after the `GetAsync` has succesfully returned?  Is there any way to make sure that the `ReadSuccessCallback` is executed in the same thread as my GUI is running in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of old school, but it should work. Place the operation in question into a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) DoWork event, with the client call you showed changed to a synchronous one, *since its now in its own thread*, pass the data of the result to the RunWorkerCompleted event and then process what is needed for the listbox at that point safely for the GUI thread.

Comment: This seems to work well enough!  Very responsive now, thanks for helping me connect the dots.

Comment: @Drewmate I wanted to give an example but ran out of time. :-( They ding me when I say look at my blog article [C# WPF: Threading, Control Updating, Status Bar and Cancel Operations Example All In One](http://omegacoder.com/?p=642) ... so I am glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update UI controls you should invoke the callback on the UI thread. Here's a good article showing different ways to do this using the [WPF Dispatcher](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher).

So one of the ways would be to do something like:

```
this.client.GetAsync<RepositoryResponse>(string.Format
("/repository?Dto={0}", reader.Dto.ToJson()),
r => {
    myListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
           //populate results int myListBox
        }); 
},
(r, x) => ReadErrorCallback(r, x));
```